# Injector error in MVC with Angular.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to use Angular.js in VS2015. I have configured Angular library using `bower` and `Grunt` in the project and created Module, Service and Controller. But when the module is applied on the View using `ng-app="MyModule"`. It gives me the below error:

> Unhandled exception at line 35, column 519 in
>   http://localhost:62112/lib/angularjs/js/angular.min.js  0x800a139e -
>   JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Please note that there are specific tags for ASP.NET MVC - the tag you used was for the *pattern*, not a specific implementation of said pattern.

Comment: Remember that you need call first all modules dependencies for your app.